# Capture the FluidMoveBehaviour completion

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, silverlight-5.0, blend

I am using FluidMoveBehaviour to control the movement of button from it's initial position to another place on the page.

Once it arrives there I want to add more (different) buttons to the original location so that the user can make a second choice.

I have all of that working almost as it should.  My only problem is that I want the new items to wait until the first button has completed it animation.

Button Clicked --> Moves to New Position --> New Items Appear.

But I cannot find a way to capture the end of the FluidMoveBehaviour Animation.  Is there a way?

- I tried to force the UpdateLayout() but then the animation is
  skipped.
- I tried watching the LayoutUpdated event, but that kicks in
  before the animation (I think it is used by the FluidMoveBehabviour
  itself, and then the animation is skipped.

Any help will be gratefully received.

Comment: +1, great question. Have you thought about just using a Storyboard instead of the behavior as an option so you can tie into its completed event?

Comment: Hi Chris, that is my option if nothing comes from here.  I'm only just beginning to put some dynamic UI in, and only found the FluidMoveBehaviour, it seemed to good to be true :). I'll dig a little deeper.